# Gradle Scala project missing startScripts

Tags: scala, gradle

I have the following [Gradle/Scala project on GitHub](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/scala-shadowjar-example) that has 3 subprojects (`client/`, `shared/` and `server/`) where:

- `client/` should produce an executable self-contained "fat jar" using the [Gradle Shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow); and
- `shared/` should produce a simple library
- `server/` like client, produces an executable self-contained "fat jar"

When I run `./gradlew clean build shadowJar` from the root directory, I get the following Gradle error:

```
:clean
:client:clean UP-TO-DATE
:server:clean UP-TO-DATE
:shared:clean UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileScala UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar
:startScripts FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':startScripts'.
> No value has been specified for property 'mainClassName'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Any idea what's going on here and what the fix is? What's this `startScripts`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that your root build script doesn't have to apply all the plugins via `allprojects` closure, since it adds `application` plugin and it's tasks to the root build script too, hence it's not configured. As it's seens, fail the root task:

```
:startScripts FAILED
```

Try to apply `application` plugin within `subprojects` closure to apply it only to `client`, `shared` and `server` subprojects.